# Create Storyboard from code behind in Uwp

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml

I want to create a storyboard from code behind, I want to achieve below Storyboard from Code Behind,

```
 <Storyboard x:Name="Counter_Animation">
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="txtCounter" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(TextBlock.Text)">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:01" Value="2"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:02" Value="1"/>
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="00:00:03" Value="0"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
```

There is a TextBlock on my page which name is txtCounter,I have tried to achieve this from code behind as below,

```
private void CounterAnimation()
    {

        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames anim = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames();
        anim.BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0);
        DiscreteObjectKeyFrame keyFrames = new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame();
        keyFrames.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
        keyFrames.Value = "2";
        keyFrames.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2);
        keyFrames.Value = "1";
        keyFrames.KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3);
        keyFrames.Value = "0";
        anim.KeyFrames.Add(keyFrames);

        Storyboard.SetTarget(anim, txtCounter);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(anim, "Text");

        storyboard.Children.Add(anim);

        storyboard.Begin();
    }
```

Code Compile well and run the problem is that on key time 1 txtCounter should show 2,on key time 2 txtCounter should show 1,on key time 3 txtCounter should show 0   but,
it directly showing me 0 (ie not showing intermediate values).
Please take a look and correct me if i am making any mistake. That will help.Thanks

Comment: You need to add multiple instance of DiscreteObjectKeyFrame to the storyboard, just like the xaml code, while you only add a single instance with 0 as its value.

Comment: Thanks @MehrzadChehraz How i missed this Let me add working code now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to write complete code here, If anyone has a better idea then please suggest 
this works for me,

```
private Storyboard GetCounterAnimation()
    {

        Storyboard storyboard = new Storyboard();
        ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames counterAnimation = new ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames
        {
            BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(0),
        };
        counterAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame { KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), Value = "2" });
        counterAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame { KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2), Value = "1" });
        counterAnimation.KeyFrames.Add(new DiscreteObjectKeyFrame { KeyTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), Value = "Inhale" });
        Storyboard.SetTarget(counterAnimation, txtCounter);
        Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(counterAnimation, "Text");
        storyboard.Children.Add(counterAnimation);
        return storyboard;
    }
```